# rails activerecord - get great grandparent value through single query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Im looking at means to optimize the number of queries done in my code.

Let's say I have this association chain:

```
A belongs to B
B belongs to C
C belongs to D
```

Let's say I have an A object and I want to get a field that appears on D. 
How do I go about it without making 3 queries (the naive approach):

```
a.b.c.d.value
```

To clarify, I already have an object of A at hand. (that's the **a** in the code above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually built the following:

```
A.where("a.id = #{a.id}").joins(b: [{c: :d}]).select("d.value").pluck(:value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here , you can use nested join query.

```
A.joins(B: [{C: :D}]).
     where(D.column_name => "Any Value")
```

Comment: that wont work for me. I already have an instance of the a object at hand so I cant use join on an object. Moreover, that is a query and I want to grab the value (which I dont know what it is)

Comment: You can update your actual scenario for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
class a
  belongs_to :b
  has_one    :d, :through :b
end

class b
  belongs_to :c
  has_one    :d, :through :c
end
```

You should then be able to use a.d